# How to Return File from SvelteKit Endpoint

Tags: rest, svelte, fs, sveltekit

I am trying to serve a PDF file that my SvelteKit app generates and allow a user to download it from an endpoint.

My project structure looks like this:

```js
---------------------
/src/routes/downloads
---------------------
[file].ts
ABC.pdf
XYZ.pdf
```

My `[file].ts` endpoint looks like this:

```js
import fs from 'fs'

// ----- GET -----
export async function get({ params }){
  //console.log(params.file) -> ABC

  var pdf = fs.readFileSync('./src/routes/downloads/'+params.file+'.pdf')

  return{
    status:200,
    headers: {
      "Content-type" : "application/pdf",
      "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename="+params.file+".pdf"
    },
    body: pdf
  }
}
```

So then when I hit `http://localhost:3000/downloads/ABC`, the PDF file named `ABC.pdf` downloads.

But my `readFileSync` path isn't something that's going to work on production. As far as I know, there is no `/src/routes` folder.

How do I serve my file from a `http://localhost:3000` url? Everything I've tried yields a `404` and it can't find the file. I'm also open to a different way of handling this scenario. This is just my best guess of how to do this in SvelteKit.

Comment: I would simply put the files in the `statics` folder instead and link to it with `blabla.pdf` directly.  This way you do not have to have an endpoint to handle this.

Comment: Hmm... that's an interesting idea. I had hoped to require that a user know the filename in order to be allowed to fetch it from my site. It seems like the `static` folder would be wide open for anyone to browse. 

Comment: that would not be so much difference with the endpoint though, but you could of course add extra security like authentication with the endpoint

Comment: As far as I know, I can't reference `./static/` from my endpoints because on the server in production, there is no "static" folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recommended way to do this, for `adapter-node`, is to place your application data in a new folder under your project's root directory (ie. alongside `/src` and `/static`). You can then read files with a relative path: `fs.readFile('./my-app-data/foo.txt')`.

For deployment, you just have to make sure to execute `node build` from the project root, as this guarantees that you have the same working directory during both development and production.

The `static` folder *works*, but it is not meant to carry application data—files in this folder represent new routes that are served directly to users, so this is not desirable if your generated files must be protected in any way. Even if they're meant to be public files, it still blurs what is supposed to be production and source data: should a new deploy overwrite all the files in `static`? If you're not careful, a naming clash could mean overwriting production data.

Comment: It also works for sqlite3 files with better-sqlite3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import.meta.glob` for this.

```js
export async function get({ params }){
  const file = `./${params.file}.pdf`;
  const pdfs = import.meta.glob(('./*.pdf', { as: 'raw' });
  const pdf = pdfs[file];

  return {
    status:200,
    headers: {
      "Content-type" : "application/pdf",
      "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename="+params.file+".pdf"
    },
    body: pdf
  }
}
```

The `import.meta.glob` in combination with the `as: 'raw'` option will effectively *embed* the contents of each file in your resulting code. (this is purely server side so no worries about shipping to much to the client)

Note that this of course means that only files present **during build** can be served this way.

Comment: Yeah, these files are generated on-the-fly as a web service. I post JSON via a `POST` request then convert them to a PDF, so I need a dynamic way of saving and reading files in the file system.

Comment: if they are generated, there is no need to read the filesystem

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this code

```js
export async function get({ params }){
  const file = `./${params.file}.pdf`;
  const pdfs = import.meta.glob(('./*.pdf', { as: 'raw' });
  const pdf = pdfs[file];

  return {
    status:200,
    headers: {
      "Content-type" : "application/pdf",
      "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename="+params.file+".pdf"
    },
    body: pdf
  }
}
```

And wondering why it doesn't work...

This is not how it's done in SvelteKit anymore.
Currently you need to return a Response object, like this:

```js
return new Response(body, { status: 200, headers: {} })
```

Hopefully this is gonna save somebody some time, I just spent few minutes debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephane suggest, put your files under `statics` folder. This way you can serve directly through a reverse proxy, like Nginx

Comment: So would my path in my endpoint be `./static/downloads/` instead of `./src/routes`? And somehow after I build my app, it will know to route `./static/downloads` to the root of my server (http://mywebsite.abc/downloads)?